# JInternalFrame won't appear on my screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I am trying to get a JInternalFrame to appear on my screen when a button is pressed, a pop up effect basically. However when the button is pressed the JInternalFrame does not appear on the screen. Also when I resize the screen all the elements expand with it, I am wondering if there is a way to get a pop up window to appear on the screen and keep the layout manager I have now still in place so that when the window is resized the elements are also resized with it

```
public class testing2 implements ActionListener {

JButton buttonAppear = new JButton();
JLayeredPane LayeredPane = new JLayeredPane();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new testing2();
}

public testing2() {



    LayeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            BorderLayout borderlayoutpane = new BorderLayout();
            LayeredPane.setLayout(borderlayoutpane);
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            BorderLayout borderlayout = new BorderLayout();
            mainPanel.setLayout(borderlayout);
            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            mainPanel.add(button, "Center");
            buttonAppear = new JButton("Panel Appear");
            buttonAppear.addActionListener(this);
            mainPanel.add(buttonAppear, "South");
            LayeredPane.add(mainPanel, 2);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(LayeredPane);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource() == buttonAppear)
    {
           JInternalFrame inFrame = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame", true, true, true, true);
           inFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);              
           inFrame.setVisible(true);
           LayeredPane.add(inFrame, 1);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> a pop up effect basically.

Then use a `JDialog`. A JInternalFrame was designed to work with a JDesktopPane.

```
mainPanel.add(button, "Center");
```

Don't use hardcode strings for the constraint. Use the field provided by the API:

```
mainPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Be consistent.

Don't know if it will make a difference but components with a higher layer number are painted on top of components with a lower index. So I would guess the panel (which is opaque) would just paint over top of the internal frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). Also read the section on [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to find the special variable for "popups" on a layered pane.